# Update yaml file using yq (String manipulation)

Tags: bash, yq

Note:
I have written this code to search for hyperlinks located at the certain path and remove https:// from the front of it, My code works fine(Given that I am not an expert in bash scripting best practices). When this statement is executed, I am getting the following error in this part of the script.

```
change1=$(yq "$variable1"="$value1" $ApiFixOrgsTags)
change2=$(yq "$variable2"="$value2" $ApiFixOrgsTags)




**Code**


ApisDraft=$(find /drafts/* -maxdepth 1 -type f)

for ApiFixOrgsTags in $ApisDraft
do
  my_var=$(yq '.securityDefinitions.[].tokenUrl' $ApiFixOrgsTags | awk -F[\(\)] '{print $2}')
  if [ ["$my_var" != 'catalog.url' ] || ["$my_var" != ''] ]; then
    ConfigProper='.configuration.properties.'
    CatelogProper='.configuration.catalogs.[].properties.'
    value='.value'
    variable1=$ConfigProper${my_var}
    variable1=$variable1${value}
    variable2=$CatelogProper${my_var}
    # to remove white all spaces
    variable1=$(echo $variable1 | sed -E 's/(\.) */\1/g')
    variable2=$(echo $variable2 | sed -E 's/(\.) */\1/g')
    echo "-----------------------------------------------"
    echo $ApiFixOrgsTags
    echo $variable1
    echo $variable2
    value1=$(yq "$variable1" $ApiFixOrgsTags)
    value2=$(yq "$variable2" $ApiFixOrgsTags)
    echo $value1
    echo $value2
    sub='https://'
    if [[ "$value1" == *"$sub"* ]]; then
      echo "https:// is there at " $variable1
      value1=${value1:8}
      echo $value1
      change1=$(yq "$variable1"="$value1" $ApiFixOrgsTags)
    fi
    if [[ "$value2" == *"$sub"* ]]; then
      echo "https:// is there at " $variable2
      value2=${value2:8}
      echo $value2
      change2=$(yq "$variable2"="$value2" $ApiFixOrgsTags)
    fi
    echo "-----------------------------------------------"
  fi
done



Error:
drafts/billpay.yml
.configuration.properties.corporate-ouath-token-url.value
.configuration.catalogs.[].properties.corporate-ouath-token-url
https://link.mx.test.dev.corp:543/
https://link.mx.test.dev.corp:543/
https:// is there at  .configuration.properties.corporate-ouath-token-url.value
link.mx.test.dev.corp:543/
Error: 1:65: invalid input text "link.mx.test.d..."
https:// is there at  .configuration.catalogs.[].properties.corporate-ouath-token-url
link.mx.test.dev.corp:543/
Error: 1:71: invalid input text "link.mx.test.d..."
```

I would welcome any suggestion to resolve this issue using yq and bash.It seems like a type cast issue in the bash.**Note: corporate-ouath-token-url can take any name so cannot hard code it**
yq tool: https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/env-variable-operators

```
sample yml

securityDefinitions:
 internal:
  tokenUrl:$(corporate-ouath-token-url)

configuration:
 properties:
  corporate-ouath-token-url:
   value: https://link.mx.test.dev.corp:543/



expected file after code is executed

securityDefinitions:
 internal:
  tokenUrl:$(corporate-ouath-token-url)

configuration:
 properties:
  corporate-ouath-token-url:
   value: link.mx.test.dev.corp:543/
```

Comment: When talking about yq in a Stack Overflow question, please be sure to always specify _which_ tool named `yq` you're using. There are at least two, and they're **very** different from each other (one is a wrapper around jq and uses jq syntax, another is completely independently developed and has its own entirely-different syntax).

Comment: Mind, in general, it'd be much better to modify your tooling to do _all_ the logic in yq (or a different YAML-aware language), instead of pulling data out from yq -> bash and then pushing results from bash -> yq. But I can only help you do that with the jq-based YQ program, and even then, I'm not going to try to reverse-engineer what all your bash does to rewrite it as jq syntax when you could explain what you want in English with examples.

Comment: On a different note -- `for ApiFixOrgTags in /drafts/*; do [ -f "$ApiFixOrgTags ] || continue` is less buggy than the `find` logic; see [BashPitfalls #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) and [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: I am using this for yq: https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/env-variable-operators

thank you for bringing that to my attention

Comment: Okay, so that's the one that's not just a wrapper around jq but its own full program with a distinct syntax. Unfortunately, I'm not as well-versed in it as I am with jq's syntax, so I'll need to let someone else answer.

Comment: It would be easier to understand your code if you post a **small** YAML sample input and the expected output of the transformation

Comment: added sample yml file

Answer (score 1):

You example is very hard to understand - you need to simplify your questions and not just paste your entire script for someone to decipher and solve.

From the sample.yml you gave, the expected output and the constraint that orporate-ouath-token-url can take any name, here is a script that would work:

```bash
yq '(.securityDefinitions.internal.tokenUrl | sub("[\$\(\)]", "")) as $name | 
  .configuration.properties[$name].value |= sub("https?:\/\/","")' file.yml
```

Explanation:

- find the token name in the security definitions.
- Remove the leading '$(' trailing ')' using `sub`
- assign this value to `$name`
- now update that property under configuration.properties
- remove the leading 'http://' or 'https://' using `sub`

Hope that enough to get you on the right track

Disclaimer: I wrote yq